# pandas count occurrence for list and column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to count the occurrence of an element from a list within a dataframe column,

for example:

```
xlst = ['pak', 'vector', 'word', 'po']


df:

col A, col B, col C

pk-121  abc   pak is going great
pk-112  xyz   word is word my friend
pk-132  agh   vector needs working
pk-321  jkl   pak is winning
pk-333  yul   vector now
```

Desired df:

```
word  count
pak   2
word  1
vector 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to match the words, then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values_counts.html):

```
import re

out = (df['col C']
 .str.extractall(f"(?P<word>{'|'.join(xlst)})")
 .droplevel('match').reset_index()
 .drop_duplicates()['word']
 .value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
)
```

Output:

```
    index  count
0     pak      2
1  vector      2
2    word      1
```

Alternative using [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
out = df['col C'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ').reindex(columns=xlst).sum()
```

Output:

```
pak       2.0
vector    2.0
word      1.0
po        0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am getting KeyError: KeyError: 'Col C'

Comment: Well, you seem to have a "col C" column (not "Col C"), please provide a reproducible input.